# Extremely slow when deploying sample projects 9.3

Tags: tds, deployment

I am super new to sitecore and going thru online training courses of "clothingCo"
When I build and deploy, as long as there is any new changes, it will take forever to build
I found this blog, but the webconfig has changed and it does not work.
Thanks for the help.
[image]

```
5>      Sitecore Connector Successfully installed to C:\inetpub\wwwroot\sitecore93.sc
5>C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\HedgehogDevelopment\SitecoreProject\v9.0\HedgehogDevelopment.SitecoreProject.targets(641,5): error : Deploy failed. Reason: The request channel timed out while waiting for a reply after 00:01:59.9979944. Increase the timeout value passed to the call to Request or increase the SendTimeout value on the Binding. The time allotted to this operation may have been a portion of a longer timeout.
5>Done building project "ClothingCompany.Items.Content.scproj" -- FAILED.
5>
5>Build FAILED.
6>------ Deploy started: Project: ClothingCompany.Items.Core, Configuration: Debug Any CPU ------
6>      TDSVersion: 6.0.0.13
6>      FrameworkVersion: 4
6>      TDS Target file version: 6.0.0.13
6>      Sitecore Connector Successfully installed to C:\inetpub\wwwroot\sitecore93.sc


Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error       Deploy failed. Reason: The request channel timed out while waiting for a reply after 00:01:59.9979944. Increase the timeout value passed to the call to Request or increase the SendTimeout value on the Binding. The time allotted to this operation may have been a portion of a longer timeout.  ClothingCompany.Items.Content   C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\HedgehogDevelopment\SitecoreProject\v9.0\HedgehogDevelopment.SitecoreProject.targets 641
```

Comment: Are you sure the TDS connection is correct, when you test it does it pass?

Comment: Yes its connected and its working perfectly, just every time when I deploy it has the same problem and after few minutes its working again

Comment: List your hardware specs, please

Comment: I'm using a laptop is brand new, its 32 gb ram and u7 1085g 2.7GHZ should be okay?

Comment: did you try this? - http://rockpapersitecore.com/2016/06/fixing-timeouts-with-tds-deploy/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Able to get it resolved by changing the file
`xxxxx.web.csproj.sitecore`

```
<Project>
  <PropertyGroup>
    <Site Server="https://xxxxxx" UserName="sitecore\admin" IsRemoteSitecore="True" />
```

the site server has to match `Hard Rock Connection`.